# Dropdown menu shows up briefly then disappears

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a dropdown menu for my Chrome extension.  There is some Javascript code that causes the menu to show up, but when I click the button, the dropdown menu only shows up for a split second before disappearing (looks like a flicker effect). Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

welcome.html

```
 <form>
                <div class="dropdown">
                <button id="dropdownbtn" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
                  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#home">Home</a>
                    <a href="#about">About</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="signup" value="Get Started">
            </form>
```

interface.js

```
    //Add dropdown
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById("dropdownbtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
      //  document.getElementById("dropdownbtn").addEventListener("mouseout", myFunction);
    });

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction()  {
    console.log("in toggle");

    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");

}
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Hello World",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "./icons/icon.png",
    "default_popup":  "account.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "css": ["style.css"],

      "js": [ "content.bundle.js", "interface.js" ],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the DOMContentLoaded. Just register the click event. And add an argument to myFunction(evt) and as soon as you enter the function use evt.preventDefault()

Comment: Have you set `.dropdown-content {display: none;}` and `.show {display: block;}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 document.getElementById("dropdownbtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction(e)  {
        e.preventDefault();
    console.log("in toggle");

   document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");

}
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/uzps6Lr1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone can explain why, but it appears to be because you are using a `<form>` element to wrap the button. Removing this and re-running the above seems to keep the dropdown active indefinitely. Perhaps the way its written assumes clicking the dropdown is submitting the form, but there is nothing to submit?